# Jemalloc for MariaDB 10 on Debian 8

Tags: debian, malloc, mariadb

I was using an alternative memory allocator for MariaDB 10 in Debian 7 Wheezy. I successfully enabled it by adding adding the path to libjemalloc.so.1 at mysqld_ld_preload in mysqlsafe. Unfortunately with the update to Debian 8 Jessie this setting seems to ignored. When I look at pmap [pid] | grep jemalloc, there is no output.

Are there alternatives to use Jemalloc or is there something wrong with my setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by only adding libjemalloc.so.1 to ld_preload instead of the full path.